# Option element doesn't default to value -angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an option a default value apparently i can't get the syntax right this is how my code looks like.. i'm using AnggularJS btw

```
<select ng-model="post.type" convert-to-number>
  <option value="1" selected>For Sale</option>
  <option value="2">Looking For</option>
  <option value="3">Promo/Events</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `post.type` first, and then just set its value (either via ng-init or inside your controller). Make sure the `type` is a string value at the end of the process.

```
<select ng-model="post.type" ng-init="post={type: '1'}">
  <option value="1">For Sale</option>
  <option value="2">Looking For</option>
  <option value="3">Promo/Events</option>
</select>
```

or inside your controller code:

```
$scope.post = { type: '1' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-init attribute in your select element and set it to the index value from source object:

```html
<select ng-init="post.type = YourArray[0]" ng-model="post.type" convert-to-number>
  <option value="1">For Sale</option>
  <option value="2">Looking For</option>
  <option value="3">Promo/Events</option>
</select>
```